# Submit form without opening new tab/window (Angular)

Tags: angular

I have looked around for answers but none seem to be working for me for some reason

I tried the answer here: [Submitting an HTML form without opening a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136349/submitting-an-html-form-without-opening-a-new-window)

I've tried preventDefault() as well but it doesn't seem to be working

But when I submit the form it still seems to be opening a new tab.

---

So I am trying to call an SSO which submits a form when they click on the SSO link. But it seems that the application that we are using keeps the old session instead of using the new session.

I was told by developers of the application that they cannot change the way they are handling the session and I need to call their `logout` before opening the SSO `login`.

I first tried using `window.open(URL)` and `window.close()` to close the logout SSO but this causes the `login` to be blocked by the browser's popup blocker (According to the PM we cannot ask the end-users to `whitelist` the website for some reason)(Trying to open both `logout` and `login` also causes `login` to be blocked)

This is the HTML for the form from the first solution that I looked at but this still opens a new tab for the logout.

```html
<form id="logoutForm" #logoutForm name="logoutForm" action="URL" method="POST" target="logoutFrame"></form>
<iframe id="logoutFrame" #logoutFrame name="logoutFrame" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

After the user clicks on the SSO, `logoutForm.nativeElement.submit()` is called to submit the form.

I've also tried the code below but the event listener doesn't seem to be getting triggered:

```js
const logoutForm = document.createElement('form')
logoutForm.action = 'https://URL/portal/logout'
logoutForm.method = 'POST'
const iFrame = document.createElement('iframe')
iFrame.name = 'logoutFrame'
logoutForm.target = 'logoutFrame'
logoutForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    // Some code here
});
logoutForm.submit();
```

Is there some simple solution that I am missing, is there something wrong with the code that I am using, or is it just impossible?(Probably not)

Note: We can't use Ajax/JQuery/PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution. Instead of using a form I just used an iFrame to handle the logout.

```js
const logoutFrame = document.createElement('iFrame')
logoutFrame.setAttribute('id', 'logoutFrame')
logoutFrame.setAttribute('style', 'display:none')
logoutFrame.setAttribute('src', URL)

document.body.appendChild(logoutFrame)
```

and removed the frame after a set timeout